# Is it possible to override assignment "=" in C#

Tags: c#

I have a complex object type for which I'm overriding the "base.ToString()" method so that it returns a string property value.

for example:

```
class foo
{
 public string StringValue{get;set;}
 public int SomeOtherValue{ get;set;}
 public override ToString()
 {
   return StringValue;
 }
}
```

So this allows me to use retrieve the value of the StringValue property easily.

Is there a way in which I can override or extend the base functionality so that I can use simple code such as below to set the `StringValue` property?

```
foo aFoo = new foo();
aFoo = "Some string value";
```

Comment: Is `aFoo.StringValue = "Some string value";` really *that* onerous to type? ;-)

Comment: Now that I read the question properly I have to agree with Adam. C# offers no support here on purpose, so that reading the code makes it clear what exactly is happening. Did we learn nothing from C++?

Comment: Btw, what would be you reason? Lazyness? (don't get me wrong, I respect that) Or the intention to confuse your fellow developers? :-D Seriously, I really hate all kinds of operator overloading. If nothing else, "Go to definition" doesn't work and you have no indication of what's going on by looking at the code.

Comment: I didn't think that there was a way, but thought that I'd ask anyway. It was really laziness on my part as I have a large amount of legacy code that will need to be changed from a straight assignment to what is required now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The assignment operator is not overridable and for good reason.

Developers are, even within the confines of C# and modern object-oriented programming languages, often "abusing" the system to make it do things it's not supposed to do. If you could assign a different meaning than passing a reference value to a variable to an assignment operator, think of the chaos that would create when inexperienced developers use it.

What you **can** do is to provide methods that allow your object to take its values from a string, like so:

```
afoo.TakeValuesFrom("Some string value");
```

or

```
MyThingy afoo = MyThingy.FromString("Some string value");
```

which would be almost identical to what you are asking, and perfectly legal and readable.

Comment: Although everyone else's answers are valid I'm selecting yours for suggesting the addition of a FromString method, which is what I'll go with.

Answer (score 11):

You can use implicit cast operator overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

Comment: This would cause the creation of an entirely new `foo`, not simply set the `StringValue` property of an existing `foo`. That said, it might still be a good enough solution depending on the usage.

Answer (score 7):

You can't overload the = operator as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sbkb459w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) for a complete list of overridable operators.

Answer (score -2):

No you cannot. It is a protected part of the C# language specification. Being able to override this would be like overriding your bodies ability to breathe air with breathing water.