# How to create object by assigning other object with similar fields

Tags: c#

I have a FullClass with some values. I want to copy some of it's values and hold it as a copy so I created coresponding CopyClass. How can I rewrite this code to achieve object creation without new keyword and just by assigning value like in the example - for simpler use.

```
class FullClass
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
}

class CopyClass
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public CopyClass(FullClass fullObject)
    {
        x = fullObject.x;
        y = fullObject.y;
    }
}

void AssignCopyObject()
{
    //I want small copy of FullClass with some of it's values
    CopyClass copyObject;

    //How I create small class object
    copyObject = new CopyClass(fullObject);

    //How I want to create it automaticly by using assign of full class object
    copyObject = fullObject; //ofc doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your looking for [Automapper](https://automapper.org/)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is wrong with the copy constructor?

Comment: @amy Nothing, it works :D I was just wondering if you can write it like I mentioned.

Comment: There are different answers to this question depending on your real use case and what you want to do; using the copy constructor is clear and shows that it is not a reference to the same object (which you could hide using implicit conversions); using inheritance confuses mutablility and you should inherit behaviour not structure.

Comment: @Bizio you can, but then the next person to read the code may not realise it's a copy not a reference.

Comment: it looks like you are asking [can I override the assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782218/is-it-possible-to-override-assignment-in-c-sharp). No you cannot, you will always need a call of `new` (either here or in a different method) because otherwise you will not have a deep copy.

Comment: or do you actually intend to have a shallow copy?

Comment: If fields from your 2 classes have the same name and you are not concerned with app performance just use reflection, no need in manual mapping. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649324/c-sharp-reflection-get-field-values-from-a-simple-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using an [implicit conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators):

```
class CopyClass
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public CopyClass(FullClass fullObject)
    {
        x = fullObject.x;
        y = fullObject.y;
    }

    public static implicit operator CopyClass(FullClass fc) => new CopyClass(fc);
}
```

But this somewhat obfuscates your intent.

Personally I'd go with `new CopyClass(fullObject);`, as that makes clear you are creating a copy of a different type.

Comment: OP is asking "achieve object creation without new keyword " you answer actually just shifts the new keyword into another place.

Comment: @MongZhu I think you are interpreting the question too literally. The OP wants to write `copyObject = fullObject;`, and this will allow them to do that.

Comment: You are probably right :) apparently Bizio is content with your solution. I tend to be pedant here on SO. Have an upvote :)